Add transition to dynamic hidden attribute using tailwindcss and vuejs
I am create UI layout using tailwind css and nuxt. 
Where sidebar is always visible at md breakpoint  and hidden on mobile devices which is only visible when menu button is clicked.
This works fine as when button is clicked sidebar is shown, as i am setting and removing hidden class 
However I want to add transition when it is show
Below is current code
<template>

   <!-- backdrop -->
   <div v-if="sidebarOpen" class="fixed md:hidden bg-black w-full min-h-dvh opacity-20" @click="hideSideBar()">
   </div>


   <div 
      :class="{ hidden: !sidebarOpen}" //<--- here i am setting this
      class="w-64 group md:block fixed  transition-all h-dvh shadow-md shadow-gray-400 shadow-x-1 mr-1 flex-none md:w-14 md:hover:w-64 overflow-hidden">
      <div class=" p-2 flex bg-violet-500 ">
         <Icon name="" size="38" />
      </div>
      <div class="overflow-y-auto h-full">
         <div class="h-full px-3 py-4 overflow-y-auto bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 pb-12">
            <ul class="space-y-2 font-medium">
               <li>
                  <a href="#"
                     class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 group">
                     <div>
                        <Icon name="mdi:view-grid-plus-outline" class="text-red-600" size="1.2rem" />
                     </div>
                     <span class="flex-1 md:hidden group-hover:block ms-3 whitespace-nowrap">Kanban</span>
                     <span
                        class="inline-flex md:hidden group-hover:block items-center justify-center px-2 ms-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 bg-gray-100 rounded-full dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">Pro</span>
                     <span
                        class="inline-flex items-center justify-center ms-3 text-sm font-medium md:hidden group-hover:block">
                        <Icon name="formkit:down" class="text-red-600" size="1.2rem" />
                     </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#"
                     class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 group">
                     <div>
                        <Icon name="mdi:view-grid-plus-outline" class="text-red-600" size="1.2rem" />
                     </div>
                     <span class="flex-1  md:hidden group-hover:block ms-3 whitespace-nowrap">Kanban</span>
                     <span
                        class="inline-flex md:hidden group-hover:block items-center justify-center px-2 ms-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 bg-gray-100 rounded-full dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">Pro</span>
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>


</template>

<script setup>

const sidebarOpen = useState('sidebarOpen')

function hideSideBar() {
   sidebarOpen.value = false;
}

</script>


Tried using https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition 
transition with :key it  does not work.
Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-evxfmn?file=app.vue

Transaction or transition?

What "doesn't work" exactly? Do you mind sharing a [repro] for this kind of question? I gave an answer recently about some transition, maybe you could give it a read for further ideas?

is transition which does not  work. eg: tailwind hover:transition-all when ever element is hover a transition can be added. similarly i wanted to show transition when ever hidden class is added and removed to element it should transition.

Do you have a repro? Have you checked my answer?

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-evxfmn?file=app.vue
Could you please share the answer link

Just realized I forgot to link the given answer haha: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78442059/8816585 I guess you still got your answer from someone else!

Reminbering display: none can't create a transition, so using Vue's transition component and v-if instead of class="hide".
Edit: using transformX instead of class="hide".

Here is a working repro!

it worked by removing the v-if and adding the key to the transition preserve the responsiveness.
had tried the v-if earlier however it tends to break the responsiveness as i want the sidebar to be always visible at md breakpoint

I edited  the answer just to check the demo.
